# What do the NBA 2k badges actually do?

Tags: nba2k16, nba2k15

In the NBA 2K games, are there any statistics available for what the badges actually -do-?

For instance:

"Alpha Dog – Steps his game up when his teammates are performing poorly"

What does that mean?  I assume I get stat increases but to what degree and which ones?

"Enforcer
What it does: What it does: Wreaks havoc on the floor with physical and tough play.
How to Get: Get 10 non-flagrant, hard fouls in a single season."

Wreaks havoc?  How?  What does that actually mean, statistically?  Does my strength stat increase?  Am I better at blocking/stealing?  Surely someone must know...